# Is there a simple way to host a JSON document you can read and update in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

What I'm trying to do is host a JSON document that will then, essentially, serve as a hosted version of [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server). I'm aware I can do something similar with [My JSON Server](https://my-json-server.typicode.com/), but I plan to move my entire architecture to GCP so want to get more familiar with it.

At first I looked into the [Storage JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api), but it seems like that's just for getting data about buckets rather than the items in the buckets itself. I created a bucket called `test-json-api` and added a `test-data.json`, but there's seemingly no way to access the data in the json file via this API.

I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible for testing purposes. In time, I'll probably use a firestore allocation, but for now I'd like to avoid all that complexity, and instead have a simple GET and a PUT/PATCH to a json file.

Comment: Do you want to update the content of the JSON file (partially)? Or do you want to be able to update the whole file?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to update the contents of the file partially. i.e. if the file contains three objects, `a` `b` and `c`, and I want to update `c`, I can send a PUT/POST/PATCH and do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Storage JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api) you are talking about are only for getting and updating the metadata and not for getting and updating the data inside the object. Objects inside the Google Cloud Storage bucket are [immutable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#immutability) and one way to update them may be to get the object data from Google Cloud Storage bucket within the code, updating it, then uploading it again into the Google Cloud Storage bucket.

As you want to deal with JSON files you may explore using [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/Entity) or [Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#in_native_mode). Also if you wish to use Firebase then you may explore [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/structure-data).

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

A **very** quick and dirty way to make it easy to read some of the information in the json doc is to use that information in the blob name. For example the key information in

```
doc = {'id':3, 'name':'my name', ... }
```

could be stored in an object called "doc_3_my name", so that it can be read while browsing the bucket. You can then download the right doc if you need to see all the original data. An object name can be up to 1024 bytes of UTF-8 (with some exclusions), which is normally sufficient for surfacing basic information.

Note that you should **never** store PII like this.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/objects